# How do I connect active speakers

Tags: audio-recording, speakers, audio-interfaces, home-studio, studio-monitors

I have a pair of [Mackie MR524](http:///https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1298913/Mackie-Mr524.html).
I would like to use them with my laptop and tablet.

[image: Mackie Back]

To simply plug in my tablet or phone without an interface what cables do I require?
I have RCA, XLR to 3.5mm XLR to TR.

I am looking to get an audio interface usb but don't want to buy the wrong device. My old set up was M-Audio PCI Delta 44 which my studio engineer friend set up for me.
I am confused when looking online as I know im not wanting to record instruments. I do however have a N.I z1 and hope to use this as a controller.

Comment: The cabling pinouts are explained in the manual. You will need to also know the pinouts for your laptop to know which cables. One word of warning - plugging powered monitors directly to a DAC with no physical fader; watch out for the huge bang that can be generated as the DAC switches on & off when you power-cycle the computer/DAC.

Comment: Thanks ive read instructions but not much info for which cables I need to get and how to look at correct interfaces.. don't have a huge amount left for audio interface as need a dj mixer for the cdjs and cables. ;-)

Comment: https://www.thomann.de/gb/behringer_ada_8200_ultragain.htm

Comment: something like this?